# Call a method of a class, when that class calls a method in an instance of another class, Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Weird question

I have an object, which creates an instance of a class like so:

```
main = new Main();

Main.proto.setup() {
  ...
  this.sys = new System(args)
  ...
}
```

And for this class System, there's a method `setMode`, so that it can be called like:

```
main.sys.setMode(args)
```

`setMode` is called in various places in Main. I have a method in Main:

```
Main.proto.update() {
  ...(No args)
}
```

Which I'd like to be called everytime setMode is called. But I don't want to have to put it everywhere that `setMode` is called. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function `setMode` in `Main`, which will call `this.sys.setMode` and `this.update`, and call this function instead of directly calling `main.sys.setMode`.

```
Main.prototype.setMode = function(...args) {
  this.sys.setMode(...args);
  this.update();
}
```

You can also overwrite the `main.sys.setMode` method like that:

```
(function(setModeCopy) {
  main.sys.setMode = function(...args) {
    main.update();
    setModeCopy.call(main.sys, ...args);
  }
}(main.sys.setMode));
```